# How do you exclude words in a list of words using bash and regular expressions?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Using bash I have something like:

`MYLIST='Word1.c Word2.c Word3.xy.c Word4.cpp Word5.xy.cpp'`

In reality the list can have hundreds of different words in different order.  I'm just trying to keep it simple.

How would I change the list to exclude words that end with `.xy.c`

I'd prefer using a regular expression if possible.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bash pattern rules as a regex-like language. In particular, Bash gives special preference to $@ and $* when applying patterns - it treats them as *lists* of words, and applies the pattern to each item in the list.

As a result, you need to write a function (so you will have a parameter list in $@ or $*) so that you can apply the pattern over the list. You would use the %% pattern, which says "match and delete the longest possible pattern". Here's is my take on it:

```
$ strip_xy_cpp() {
>     RESULT="${*%%*.xy.cpp}"
>     echo "$RESULT"
> }

$ echo $MYLIST
Word1.c Word2.c Word3.xy.c Word4.cpp Word5.xy.cpp

$ NEWLIST=$( strip_xy_cpp $MYLIST )

$ echo $NEWLIST
Word1.c Word2.c Word3.xy.c Word4.cpp
```

Comment: thanks, if no other solutions are as straight forward I'll use this.  But I thought there was a way to use actual regex in bash?  something like `varname=${varname regex}` and you get back what you want. Apparently I was mistaking?

Comment: The `=~` operator of `[[` evaluates the left hand string against the right hand extended regular expression (ERE). After a successful match, `BASH_REMATCH` can be used to expand matched groups from the 
                pattern. Quoted parts of the regex become literal. To be safe & compatible, put the regex in a parameter and do `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that does not use REGEX, but it is simple script at least:

I tested the script:

```
str="Word1.c Word2.c Word3.xy.c Word4.cpp Word5.xy.cpp"
echo $str
for file in $str
do
    if [ ! ${file: -5} == ".xy.c" ]
    then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

This could be changed to take in a parameter:

```
for str in $1
do
    if [ ! ${str: -5} == ".xy.c" ]
    then
        echo $str
    fi
done
```

- The `for str in $1` section iterates through each file (or word)
  separated by a space.
- The `! ${str: -5} == ".xy.c"` section checks to see if the `str` string's last five characters are equal to `.xy.c` . If they are equal, then the `!` makes the `if` statement result in false. Thus that particular `str` string is not printed with `echo`

You could then run:

```
$ bash scriptName.sh "Word1.c Word2.c Word3.xy.c Word4.cpp Word5.xy.cpp"
```

and if you want to store the output in a file:

```
$ bash scriptName.sh "Word1.c Word2.c Word3.xy.c Word4.cpp Word5.xy.cpp" > result.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ my_list='Word1.c Word2.c Word3.xy.c Word4.cpp Word5.xy.cpp'
$ read -ra my_arr <<< "$my_list"
$ result_arr=()
$ for i in "${my_arr[@]}"; do [[ $i != *.xy.c ]] && result_arr+=("$i"); done
$ printf '%s\n' "${result_arr[@]}"
Word1.c
Word2.c
Word4.cpp
Word5.xy.cpp
```

**As a side note:**

By convention, environment variables (`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `SHELL`, ...) and internal shell variables (`BASH_VERSION`, `RANDOM`, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since 
                variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Comment: I would need the variable to stay as a single line with words space separated.  It seems complex, would sed help, how could that do it?

Comment: Just change the last line to `printf -v  var '%s' "${result_arr[*]}"`. You can then use `"$var"` to do whatever you want.

Comment: ...or just use `"${result_arr[*]}"` as is if you wish.